# Query rows where first_name contains at least 2 vowels, and the number of occurences of each vowel is equal

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem: Show all rows in table where column first_name contains at least 2 vowels (a, e, i, o, u), and the number of occurences of each vowel is the same.

Valid example: `Alexander`, "e" appears 2 times, "a" appears 2 times. That is coreect.

Invalid example: `Jonathan`, it has 2 vowels (a, o), but "o" appears once, and "a" appears twice, the number of occurences is not equal.

I've solved this problem by calculating each vowel, and then verify every case (A E, A I, A O etc. Shortly, each combination of 2, 3, 4, 5). With that solution, I have a very long WHERE. Is there any shorter way and more elegant and simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it in TSQL in MS SQL Server 2019.
I know its not exactly what you wanted. Just an interesting thing to try. Thanks for that.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Samples

SELECT n.Name
INTO   #Samples
FROM
       (
           SELECT 'Ravi' AS Name
           UNION
           SELECT 'Tim'
           UNION
           SELECT 'Timothe'
           UNION
           SELECT 'Ian'
           UNION
           SELECT 'Lijoo'
           UNION
           SELECT 'John'
           UNION
           SELECT 'Jami'
       ) AS n

SELECT   g.Name,
         IIF(MAX (g.Repeat) = MIN (g.Repeat) AND SUM (g.Appearance) >= 2, 'Valid', 'Invalid') AS Validity
FROM
         (
             SELECT      v.value,
                         s.Name,
                         SUM (LEN (s.Name) - LEN (REPLACE (s.Name, v.value, ''))) AS Repeat,
                         SUM (IIF(s.Name LIKE '%' + v.value + '%', 1, 0)) AS Appearance
             FROM        STRING_SPLIT('a,e,i,o,u', ',') AS v
             CROSS APPLY #Samples AS s
             GROUP BY    v.value,
                         s.Name 
         ) AS g
WHERE    g.Repeat > 0
GROUP BY g.Name
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVxTB.png)

we can replace STRING_SPLIT with a temp table for supporting lower versions

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Vowels

SELECT C.Vowel
INTO   #Vowels
FROM
       (
           SELECT 'a' AS Vowel
           UNION
           SELECT 'e'
           UNION
           SELECT 'i'
           UNION
           SELECT 'o'
           UNION
           SELECT 'u'
       ) AS C

SELECT   g.Name,
         IIF(MAX (g.Repeat) = MIN (g.Repeat) AND SUM (g.Appearance) >= 2, 'Valid', 'Invalid') AS Validity
FROM
         (
             SELECT      v.Vowel,
                         s.Name,
                         SUM (LEN (s.Name) - LEN (REPLACE (s.Name, v.Vowel, ''))) AS Repeat,
                         SUM (IIF(s.Name LIKE '%' + v.Vowel + '%', 1, 0)) AS Appearance
             FROM        #Vowels AS v
             CROSS APPLY #Samples AS s
             GROUP BY    v.Vowel,
                         s.Name
         ) AS g
WHERE    g.Repeat > 0
GROUP BY g.Name
```

Comment: Thank you for this approach! I've solved my problem using your answer. I only had to do some changes, because IIF is not in Oracle SQL, and then it worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Appreciate the comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   (
           -- Step 2: Count the frequency of each vowel
           SELECT letter,
                  COUNT(*) As frequency
           FROM   (
             -- Step 1: Find all the vowels
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(name), '[aeiou]', 1, LEVEL) AS letter
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(LOWER(name), '[aeiou]')
           )
           GROUP BY letter
         )
         -- Step 3: Filter out names where the number of vowels are
         --   not equal or the vowels do not occur at least twice
         --   and there are not at least 2 different vowels.
         HAVING MIN(frequency) >= 2
         AND    MIN(frequency) = MAX(frequency)
         AND    COUNT(*)       >= 2
       );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (name) AS
SELECT 'Alexander' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Johnaton' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Anna' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME |
> | --- |
> | Alexander |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c7c8080afeeb208dcf2b6ef6815291b)*